# How to find worker info of a Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark program that uses several clusters.

How can I find out which machine each cluster is on, considering:

- I do not have access to the web UI (working from a terminal remotely)
- I am using Python and **only** Python, no Java or Scala
- Any **unique** identifier of the machine is welcome (IP address, name, serial number...)
- I need a human readable value that I can print to the terminal

I have seen solutions that merely give the line `spark.metrics.worker` but they do not specify what "`spark`" is in this context (I can deduce that it is not the SparkCluster).

Is it maybe possible to implement a solution like [this one](https://kb.databricks.com/metrics/spark-metrics.html), but with a configuration that outputs worker information instead of general stats?

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# example of an ideal solution

spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("myCoolApp")
    .config("spark.workers.show", "True")
    .getOrCreate()
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think Spark REST API or Metrics system (=Databricks example you have a link to) are both generic solutions, and leave up to you to perform any additional parsing and filtering to get what you need,